# laravel eloquent: get first time customers with their upcoming reservation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models: `Customer` and `Reservation`.

Would like to get: *first time customers with their upcoming reservation*.

Currently getting customers with upcoming reservations like this:

```
Customer::whereHas('reservation', function($q) {
  $q->where('date','>',Carbon::now();
})
->with('reservation');
```

How do I:

1. only get customers that don't have previous reservations
2. order the customers by reservation date

The other way around might be easier:

```
Reservation::where('date','>',Carbon::now())->with('customer')->orderBy('date');
```

But then still not clear how best to only get their customers who have their first reservations. Plus, I prefer to end up with a collection of Customers with their Reservations instead of Reservations with their Customers.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I recommend declaring a new relationship in Customer Model:

```
 public function firstUpcomingReservation()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Reservation::class, 'customer_id')->where('date','>',Carbon::now());
    }
```

then you can use that relation like:

```
   $values=  Customer::has('firstUpcomingReservation')->whereDoesntHave('reservation', function($q) {
            $q->where('date','<',Carbon::now());
        })->with('firstUpcomingReservation')->get();
```

Comment: thanks, the extra `whereDoesntHave` is useful. Remarks: a) how to sort by reservation date? b) relationship -I think- should be hasMany(...)->limit(1) [note: limit(1) in `whereHas()` will not work